# Gm library doesnt show unicode character

Tags: node.js, unicode, gm

So I wanted to display unicode characters with [gm](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html) and therefore decided to use a unicode font. I ended using arial unicode ms, (I couldn't figure out how to use the google noto family and 'connect' the seperate ttf files).

After trying to print a character that arial unicode ms included ex:(unicode 5909 (変)) it showed as ?.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
gm('./folder/some_image.jpg')
.font('./folder/arial_unicode_ms.ttf')
.fill('#000000')
.fontSize('20px')
.drawText(0, 0, `変`);
```

So the question is how to print unicode characters with gm in nodejs.